# How to update "strtotime" format

Tags: php, string, server-side, countdown

I am using PHP to create a countdown functionality. It does work well given the limitation of the server side countdowns but the format is different from what I want to achieve.

I use the following code to achieve that:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
$date = strtotime("November 22, 2017 12:01 AM");
$remaining = $date - time();

if ($remaining > 0) {
    $days_remaining = floor($remaining / 86400);
    $hours_remaining = floor(($remaining % 86400) / 3600);
    $minutes_remaining = floor(($remaining % 3600) / 60);
}
?>
```

And output it using:

```
<div class="category-countdown">
    <? if ($remaining > 0) { ?>

    <div class="category-countdown--left">{{end-day}}</div>
    <div class="category-countdown--right">
      <div class="category-countdown__timer">
              <?= $days_remaining ?> : <?= $hours_remaining ?> : <?= $minutes_remaining ?>
      </div>
      <div class="category-countdown__annotation">days : hours : minutes</div>
    </div>
    <? } ?>
</div>
```

The current format is : 1 (day) : 3(hours) : 5(minutes)

What I want to achieve is : 01 (day) : 03(hours) : 05(minutes)

Can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `str_pad()` like this,

```
str_pad($var, 2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Apply this in:

```
   $days_remaining  = str_pad(floor($remaining / 86400), 2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT);
   $hours_remaining     = str_pad(floor(($remaining % 86400) / 3600), 2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT);
   $minutes_remaining   = str_pad(floor(($remaining % 3600) / 60), 2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($remaining > 0) {
$days_remaining = floor($remaining / 86400);
$days_remaining = sprintf('%02d', $days_remaining);
$hours_remaining = sprintf('%02d', floor(($remaining % 86400) / 3600));
$minutes_remaining = sprintf('%02d', floor(($remaining % 3600) / 60));
```

}

Comment: What Problem With it ?